# NumberPicker can't choose the first value

Tags: android, numberpicker

Hey so I am using `NumberPicker` and my first value is "all" which means to like reset the `EditText` to 0 and after all I have numbers, the problem is that when I get into the picker and directly select "all" it just doesn't do anything, It will keep the `NumberPicker` on the last number I picked and if I want to choose the all option I have to scroll up/down and then return to the "all" and choose it..

My code looks like this:

```
  String[] values = new String[21];
        values[0] = "All";
        for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++)
            values[i] = "" + (i + 15);
        NumberPicker agePicker = new NumberPicker(this);
        agePicker.setMinValue(15);
        agePicker.setMaxValue(15 + (values.length - 1));
        agePicker.setDisplayedValues(values);
        agePicker.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

        NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener ageListener = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                AgeFilterTemp = newVal;
            }
        };


        agePicker.setOnValueChangedListener(ageListener);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(agePicker);
        builder.setTitle("Maximum age");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                if (AgeFilterTemp != 15 && AgeFilterTemp != 0) {
                    AgeFilter.setText("" + AgeFilterTemp);
                    setAgeFilter(AgeFilterTemp);
                } else {
                    AgeFilter.setText("Age");
                    adapter.setListData(listData);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }

            }
        });
        builder.show();
```

Comment: Did you simply debug your listener to see what is happening ?

Comment: @AxelH , It just able to choose the first value after scrolling to another value and getting back to the first, if you open it and click "ok" immediately it won't change anything.

Comment: That's testing, not debugging. Check what is the value received in the listener.